# console.log stopping alert after it

Tags: javascript, version-control

I am new to javascript, I am trying to create a contact from and validate it, but, as you can see down below, I don't know if it is...

```
console.log('Email is valid!');
```

... or anything else but the other part of alerts wont work after that! Anyone know how to fix it? I would appreciate your help!

```
if (name === '') {
  alert('Pls enter your name!')
} else if (name.length < 2) {
  alert('Pls enter a valid name! Longer than 2 letters');
} else if (name.length > 20) {
  alert('Pls enter a valid name! Less than 20 letters');
} else if (email === '') {
  alert('Empty Email. Pls enter your email!')
} else if (!validateEmail(email)) {
  alert('Email is not valid!');
} else if (validateEmail(email)) {
  console.log('Email is valid!');
} else if (message.length < 1) {
  alert('Pls enter a Message!')
} else if (message.length < 5) {
  alert('Pls enter a message longer than 5 letters!')
```

Comment: only ONE of `if .. else/if ... else/if` alerts will ever be executed - because of how if/else works - you probably don't want `else if`, just a bunch of `if`

Comment: But it works for name and email, and if i put the message validation else if before the email i will get the alert of message but the then the email doesnt work propelry

Answer (score 0):

Please read [`if-else-if`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) how it works, it only executes **one** of all the conditions and exits immediately. If you want to execute all of the alerts, just do a bunch of `ifs`:

```
if (name === '') {
  alert('Pls enter your name!')
} 

if (name.length < 2) {
  alert('Pls enter a valid name! Longer than 2 letters');
} 

if (name.length > 20) {
  alert('Pls enter a valid name! Less than 20 letters');
} 

if (email === '') {
  alert('Empty Email. Pls enter your email!')
} 

if (!validateEmail(email)) {
  alert('Email is not valid!');
} 

if (validateEmail(email)) {
  console.log('Email is valid!');
} 

if (message.length < 1) {
  alert('Pls enter a Message!')
} 

if (message.length < 5) {
  alert('Pls enter a message longer than 5 letters!')
}
```

Comment: Oh! okay! Thanks

Comment: Oh damn! I just tried it and all the alerts go at once!

Comment: That's what you're looking for. The better approach here is to concatenate the error messages into one string and alert once.